# How do I solve the following error when I'm trying to install bob.blitz?

Tags: python

```
pip install bob.blitz
Collecting bob.blitz
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9b/00/93dffb581fa189d6a94504babf1136664e9c364643de6ded88b76b6aa520/bob.blitz-2.0.16.zip
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Sapa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qcgio22f\bob.blitz\setup.py", line 70, in <module>
        system_include_dirs=system_include_dirs,
      File "c:\users\sapa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\bob\extension\__init__.py", line 419, in __init__
        boost_pkg = boost(boost_req.replace('boost', '').strip())
      File "c:\users\sapa\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\bob\extension\boost.py", line 69, in __init__
        raise RuntimeError("could not find boost's `version.hpp' - have you installed Boost on this machine?")
    RuntimeError: could not find boost's `version.hpp' - have you installed Boost on this machine?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Sapa\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qcgio22f\bob.blitz\
```

I've already tried  pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Hi Sava, First, can you fix the formatting of your question? Second, looks like you need to install boost. Check your library dependencies and see what version of boost you need: https://www.boost.org/

Comment: I did install boost, and nothing changed..